# Determine all sequence $a_{n}$ such $ a_{n+2}$ is divisible by $a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine all sequence $a_{0},a_{1},a_{2},\cdots$ of postive integers with
$a_{0}\ge 2015$ such that for all integers $n\ge 1$

(1)$ a_{n+2}$ is divisible by $a_{n}$

(2) $|S_{n+1}-(n+1)a_{n}|=1$ where
$S_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}+a_{n-1}-\cdots+(-1)^{n+1}a_{0}$$

I guess this sequence maybe can't exist? This is last problem  [APMO2015](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1071769p4663898)

Comment: There are lots of sequences that fit this description.  Constant sequences for example.  Also, any geometric sequence (provided $a_0\geq 2015$ of course).